# Tracking actual resource consumption (CPU,RAM) of VMs in OpenStack environment

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit, openstack

we are using OpenStack and try to find a way to measure the actual consumption of CPU, Storage and RAM on the physical hosts.

The way I read it there is no way with nova host-describe or telemetry to get actual resource usage only a projected usage. 
http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/common/nova-show-usage-statistics-for-hosts-instances.html

So is there a tool or some low level mechanism how to query how much the VMs from one tenant are consuming in terms of resources on the different hosts?

Comment: What's wrong with ceilometer?

Comment: Yes, looked at the measurements there but if I get it right this only accounts for the VMs resource usage in relation to OpenStack. I does not tell you what is actually happening on the host system.